# UITextField input issue

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

In my application there have two Outlet, one is UItextfield and another is UIWebview, textfield used to get the url request by the user and shown it in webview, but I met a problem is when finish the typing in my textfield, and click GO button(return) in the keyboard, that is nothing happen in my webview, my source code as shown in below:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"clicked");
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [mywebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[textField text]]]];

    return YES;
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the delegate of the textfield to be the class with the textFieldShouldReturn: method?